# ImportError: [libraryname].so: undefined symbol: [function name]

Tags: python, gstreamer, importerror, extending

I'm extending my Python program with a C module that uses the GstPhotography interface for GStreamer. My C module compiles fine, but when I try running it from Python, I get this error:

```
$python Program.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "Program.py", line 10, in <module>
     import MyPythonClass
   File "/path/MyPythonClass.py", line 19, in <module>
     import my_c_module
ImportError: /path/my_c_module.so: undefined symbol: gst_photography_get_type
```

I'm not really sure what this means, because I never use gst_photography_get_type in my_c_module.cpp--it's a function implemented in the GstPhotography source code.

Answer (score 0):

It means that you didn't link against enough libraries, either because it wasn't indicated in the pkgconfig file, or you didn't refer to the pkgconfig file in the first place.